# Swing - replacement for Qt signal/slots

Tags: java, swing, qt, pyqt, signals-slots

In Qt GUIs it is very convenient use signals & slots - it decouple events passing. When I create some widget that throw signal, I don't have to know in advance who can get it, and later with `connect` I specify connections.

What is parallel in Java/Swing? Can you point to good resources on this issue?

Comment: It's been a long time since I used Java, but don't you just add listeners to the events?

Comment: @San Jacinto: Qt also has events, but also signals & slots which is more convenient frequently

Comment: Qt events are not analogous to Swing events. Swing event listeners are closer to Qt's event filters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If none of the existing [`EventListener`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EventListener.html) implementations meet your requirements, you can create your own custom event. Every [`JComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) contains a field of type [`EventListenerList`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html). You can use the approach outlined in the [`EventListenerList`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/event/EventListenerList.html) API to enable your custom [`JComponent`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) subclass to fire your custom event.

Regarding the signal/slot mechanism, Swing has several ways to implement the [observer pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066590/gui-problem-after-rewriting-to-mvc/3072979#3072979).

Answer (score 1):

This [Event Listener tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html) goes through the basics of handling events with listeners.

Connecting your slot for a signal is analogous to adding your EventListener to an event-producing object.